# Update State from an object within an array using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui

There's an easy work around of just not doing it this way, but I'm losing my mind as to why it doesn't work.

Here's my full code

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { Stack, Input, Button, ListItem, UnorderedList, Checkbox } from '@chakra-ui/react'

type Todo = {
  text: string,
  complete: boolean,
  id: number
}

const Todo: NextPage = () => {
  let id = 1
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<Todo>({ text: '', complete: false, id: 36})
  const [completed, setComplete] = useState([false, false])
  const [todoList, updateList] = useState<Todo[]>([
    { text: 'Master NextJS', complete: false, id: 12 },
    { text: 'Become a Software Developer', complete: false, id: 72 }
  ])
  const handleChange = (event) => setTodo(prev => ({...prev, text: event.target.value}))
  const values = todo.text
  
  const updateCheck = (event, id) => {
    updateList(todos => {
      todos[todoList.findIndex(x => x.id == id)].complete = true
      return todos
    })
  }
  
  const addTodo = () => {
    if (todo.text == ''){
      alert('You need to set some text')
      return
    }
    updateList(prev => ([...prev, todo])),
    setTodo(prev => ({...prev, text: ''}))
    alert("New todo set!")
  }

  
  return (
    <>
      <div className='rounded-md p-5 bordered border-2'>
        <Input variant='filled' className="w-full" onChange={handleChange} value={todo.text} placeholder="Enter what you need to do..."/>
        <p>{values}</p>
        <Button colorScheme='teal' variant='outline' py={3} onClick={addTodo}>Add todo</Button>
        <ul>
          {todoList.map(todo => {
            return (
            <li>
              <Checkbox key={todo.id} onChange={(e) => updateCheck(e, todo.id)} isDisabled={todo.complete}>{todo.text}</Checkbox>
            </li> 
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

I'm creating a todo app with chakra ui, and whenever the user checks the checkbox the todo is supposed to become disabled. To acomplish this, I've set the `isDisabled` prop of the Checkbox component to be `todos.complete`

Todos themselves are an array of objects (named todoList) with the following  type:

```
type Todo = { 
  id: number
  text: string
  complete: boolean
}
```

stored in state with the 'useState' hook. The code for my updateList hook is as follows:

```js
  const updateCheck = (event, id) => {
    updateList(todos => {
      todos[todoList.findIndex(x => x.id == id)].complete = true
      return todos
    })
  }
```

Whenever I check the value of the `complete` field after this function it's true. But after checking the checkbox, it does not disable and just allows me to keep checking and unchecking the box.

**BUT**

The code *does* work (as in, all checked todos disable) whenever I start typing in the todo input box. This tells me that there's something wrong with the checkbox's handleChange function. But it fires whenever I put alerts in the function, and it successfully changes the complete field to true?

I'm really annoyed and just going to sleep on this. Thanks for any help

Comment: I believe you should do 

```  const updateCheck = (event, id) => {
    updateList(todos => {
      todos[todoList.findIndex(x => x.id == id)].complete = true
      return [...todos]
    })
  }```

Comment: @Crocsx Don't do that! That would mutate state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component probably isn't being rerendered because your state mutation returns the same array it gets passed in. You also shouldn't be mutating the object inside the array. Instead, create a new one.

```
const updateCheck = (event, id) => {
  updateList(todos =>
    todos.map(todo => todo.id != id ? todo : { ...todo, complete: true })
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what worked. Looks like I need more practice with immutable data structures